# How to parse my json object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-web-api

My program sends some JSON to my API (which works fine):

```
var result = await fetch('http://localhost:58553/api/Foo', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
});    

var contentResult = await result.text();

var contentResultObject = JSON.parse(contentResult);

console.log(contentResult);
console.log(contentResultObject);
console.log(contentResultObject.code);
```

The output of `console.log`:

```
"{\"code\":1,\"probability\":0.985368549823761}"
{"code":1,"probability":0.985368549823761}
undefined
```

Any reason why this isn't working? My API simply returns a string:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

Comment: `contentResultObject ` should be a JSON object. Further, the `result` should be by default JSON object

Comment: I dont know why do you have problem with your result? But i have tested its working..

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Your JSON string looks like it's been encoded twice.

Comment: @nikc.org hmm... how do I go about and fix that?

Comment: you done need to convert the result into string. convert it into json
var contentResult = await result.json();

Answer (score 1):

Your output of `contentResult` looks like your payload has been double encoded. You can verify this by logging `typeof contentResultObject`, which should show `string`.

To fix the problem you will ideally address the double encoding issue on the server, but if you can't you can simply apply `JSON.parse` twice.

Comment: it states string